# SSL Socket Error(Java to Python)

Tags: java, python, sockets, ssl, networking

I am trying to send an wav audio from a java client on ssl socket to a python server on ssl socket but I am having numerous issues that I can't seem to understand why. I am new to networking. I don't know where my code is going wrong.

Client Code(Python) :

```
import socket, ssl, sys 
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
print('Listening...')
conn, addr = s.accept()
print "accepted !"
try:
    sslSock  = ssl.wrap_socket(conn,server_side=True, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,ciphers="ADH-AES256-SHA")
    print ("SSL wrap succeeded for sever",addr)
except:
    print "SSL wrap failed for server "
    sys.exit(0)

outfile = open("newfile.wav", 'ab')
while True:
    data = sslSock.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    outfile.write(data)
sslSock.close()
s.close()
outfile.close()
print ("Completed.")
```

Server Code (Java):

```
public class sslSocketAudio {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String FILE_TO_SEND = "" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + "src"+ "/" + "Cloud04-task3.wav" + "";

    File soundFile = AudioUtil.getSoundFile(FILE_TO_SEND);
    System.out.println("File to be sent: " + soundFile);

    int port = 50007;
    int bufferZise = 1024;
    String hostname = "localhost";
    try{
        SocketFactory socketFactory =  SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        Socket sock = socketFactory.createSocket(hostname, port);
        System.out.println("socket made!");
        sock.setSendBufferSize(bufferZise);
        OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(soundFile);
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        System.out.println("Done Sending.");
        sock.close();
        in.close();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("file sent : shutdown");
    }catch (IOException e ){
        System.err.printf(e.toString());
        System.err.printf("Error Happened");
    }

}
}
public class AudioUtil {
    public static File getSoundFile(String fileName) {
        File soundFile = new File(fileName);
        if (!soundFile.exists() || !soundFile.isFile())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not a file: " + soundFile);
        return soundFile;
    }
}
```

Please Help, I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: Any exceptions or errormessages?

Comment: --In python the error is  :     data = sslSock.recv(1024)
NameError: name 'sslSock' is not defined                                                                    --In Java :                                                                                                                   java.net.SocketException: Connection resetError Happened

Comment: I think that is because `sslSock` is out of scope in the `while` loop, its scope is limited to the `try` block.

Comment: So, what am i supposed to do about it ?

Comment: You can move the `while` loop and the `sslSock.close()` statement inside the `try` block.

Comment: Or, you can declare `sslSock` before the `try` block, something like `sslSock = None`

Comment: That didn't work ...

Comment: Do you get the same error in the Python code ?

Comment: No the exception occurs but the problem happens when the ssl sock is trying to be created. could this have to do with anything about the key and certification. Should one be created at all ?

Comment: This is a bit confusing. You say Java is your Server and Python your client. But it seems Connection-wise it is the other way round. Python accepts the connection established in Java?

Comment: Oh I thought I said in my question post that Java is my client and Python is my server listening to just accept and make the audio wav file. I'm a little lost on how to make the SSL socket on python or rather why it is not connecting with the Java ssl socket... Essentially I want to use the Java on android to record audio with the microphone and send it to my intel Edison.

Comment: Essentially, the error output is this:    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 511, in __init__
    raise ValueError("certfile must be specified for server-side "
ValueError: certfile must be specified for server-side operations                          does this mean i have to create a certfile? if so how ?